# RxJava: throw IllegalArgumentException when use 'first' operator

Tags: java, android, rx-java

When I use Observable.first() operator, I got a IllegalArgumentException with message "Sequence contains too many elements".

Here is a simplified test code can reproduce the exception:

```
Subject<Integer, Integer> subject = BehaviorSubject.create();

subject.first()
       .subscribe(integer -> subject.onNext(1));

subject.onNext(0);
```

These code is extracted from a very complex real project, I don't think I can easily explain why I need to do this strange thing.

So I just want to ask a question:
Is this a bug in RxJava or incorrect usage by myself?

If it a incorrect usage, I think I need to rewrite the logic to avoid these code.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [known bug](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/3346) with the take operator (used by first) that has a re-entrancy problem and the next release, 1.0.15, will contain the fix. No ETA on it, sorry.

By the way, if this bug weren't there, why do you do this thing in your code? Do you want to signal something to the other subscribers?

**Edit**

Workaround:

Any operator doing serialization can be used for working around the bug. Maybe the simplest one is to use `BehaviorSubject.create().toSerialized()`.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Yes, the subject is for implementing a data store singleton, which has many observer listening to the data change. subject.first() block and subject.onNext(0) block are call by different part of code (each part of code has a step to update the data store).